# In JPQL, is it possible to write a "select new" with a list as parameter?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I wonder if it is possible to write a "select new" query with a list as a parameter.

For example, in one hand, I have a table "father" and a table "children". A children has only one father and a father has multiple children. In the other hand, I have an object "FatherDto" which the constructor need a "Father" object and a list of children.

Is is possible, in JPQL, to write something like

```
SELECT new FatherDto(fat, childrenList) 
FROM fat, (select new Child(ch) from children ch where ...) as childrenList from children child
WHERE ...
```

The objective is to get, using only one query, a list of father with a list of children in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, because "subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause" (from spec).

Besides, the constructor must get only single_values_path_expression. Excerpt from the specification:

```
select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_item {, select_item}*
select_item ::= select_expression [ [AS] result_variable]
select_expression ::=
  single_valued_path_expression |
  scalar_expression |
  aggregate_expression |
  identification_variable |
  OBJECT(identification_variable) |
  constructor_expression
constructor_expression ::=
  NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::=
  single_valued_path_expression |
  scalar_expression |
  aggregate_expression |
  identification_variable
aggregate_expression ::=
  { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_valued_path_expression) |
  COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_valued_path_expression |
      single_valued_object_path_expression) |
  function_invocation
```

and I am not sure whether in `new FatherDto(fat, childrenList)` childrenList is considered a path expression.

Comment: Doesn' t the second constructor expression get a single_valued_path_expression? `new Child(ch) from children ch`

Comment: That yes, but not the part `new FatherDto(fat, childrenList)` (childrenList is not single valued)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll write a class which do what I want.